# signed integer, arithmetic shift to the left

Tags: ios, swift, integer, byte, bit

I'm trying to understand how "signed integer" and "arithmetic left shift" works in swift and iOS.

In the book, swift programming language 3.0, it says

[image]

I tried it out with the following code:

[image]

I understand with signed integer, binary representation of -120 is 10001000, so shifting one place to the left would result in 00010000, which is equal to 16 (as shown by the code). But 16 is not double of -120

the statement made by the book is incorrect, right? or is there something i'm missing?

Comment: This is all dependent on what type of integer you are using. Try changing `negative120` to a Swift Integer instead of `Int8` like `let negative120: Int = -120`, and you'll notice the value doubles.

Comment: Also worth noting: the bit shift operator shifts bits. It doesn't double, necessary. It sometimes doubles values, and can be handy for that. If wanted reliable multiplication by 2, then you should ... multiply by 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're experiencing Integer overflow. The doubling effect only works so long as there is room for all the bits.

This example would work if you use `Int16`, `Int32`, `Int64` or `Int` (which maps to either `Int32` or `Int64`, depending on the system). Consider the case of `Int16`.

`-120`'s binary representation as an `Int16` is `1111 1111 1000 1000`. Left shifting by one, we get: `1111 1111 0001 0000`. This is the binary representation for `-240`, as you would expect. Here's the code for it:

```
let a: Int16 = -120
print(a << 1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying the concept. Could you please tell me how to deal with integer overflow when I'm working with bits? Most of the time, everything works perfectly, but there are occasional edge cases whose result is not what we expect. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @TonyStark Well it depends. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I guess I'm asking a very general question. I don't have a particular purpose in mind. Just want to know how to deal with integer overflow in general when I do encounter them I guess. Sorry couldn't be more specific

Comment: @TonyStark There's no one size fits all approach, besides using Integer datatypes that are large enough to fit whatever values you expect to encounter